# Simple MySQL Two Table Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

```
1st table :-

id name dept
1  John dept1
2  Mary dept2
3  Dave dept3
4  John dept4
5  John dept5


2nd table :-

id submitter dept
1  Rupert    dept3
2  Joe       dept1
3  Lisa      dept2
4  Louise    dept4
5  Tom       dept5
```

what i would like is a query to allow people in the name column in the first table to only show records based on their matching departments eg John in table one will return the 3 records in table 2 (id 2,4 and 5)

So far i have tried `SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.dept = table2.dept AND table1.name='John'`

Comment: This is where im stuck - so far i have tried
SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.dept = table2.dept
AND table1.name='John'

Comment: You need to look into JOIN's

Comment: Thankyou JemoeE will have a read now :)

Comment: And what is wrong with the results you get with the query?

Comment: You have many unclosed questions (IMHO) with possible solutions; they should be marked as solved in order to properly close those questions, including this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem, you need to make a join between the two tables using the field dept and filter your results by the name of the requester, in the first table.

```
SELECT t2.submitter, t2.dept
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.dept = t2.dept
WHERE t1.name = :person_name
```

[Documentation and examples](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) (you can also look at the left menu at Inner, right, full and self join's).